# How to serve fonts from public folder allowing "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fonts, public

I have fonts folder in "public" folder. I am using font paths in css file like:

```
https://example.com/fonts/icomoon.eot?2p5wfs
```

I am having this issue:

```
from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

It works if I turn on my chrome "CORS" extension. How can I load icons without using this chrome extension?

Comment: The CORS should be enabled on the server which is serving your fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => 'https://example.com',
    'Access-Control-Request-Method' => %w{GET POST OPTIONS}.join(",")
  }
```

Comment: where does this go exactly?

Comment: @vikingsteve   /config/application.rb

Comment: I see. So that's ruby? Any idea how I can do this for react.

Comment: @vikingsteve https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch